# Is Mac OsX (from 10.5.8 ) compatible with CIFS used in Windows Server 2012?

Tags: mac-osx, samba, windows-server-2012

I need to check if our Graphics Office (all using Mac's) are compatibles with our future Windows Server 2012 file server. The oldest OsX version we have is 10.5.8. 
Thanks

Comment: Samba is not used by Win Server 2012, they have their own implemenation of CIFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a definitive statement anywhere.

However, one of the nice things about Microsoft's trial licensing is they explicitly support test systems (it wouldn't be a very good trial if they didn't). I'd install Windows Server 2012 on an old workstation, set up a file share, and just check to make sure one of the mac's in your office can connect okay (and then please post back here so we have a record of the results).

Also, with the direction Apple is moving right now, I'd be just as worried (or more) about the new 10.8 Mountain Lion's as I was the old 10.5's. It seems that the stronger Apple's market position gets, the less they care about interoperating with other systems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to. OS X 10.5 supports the SMB1 protocol which is still supported in server 2012, Please look at the matrix provided on the following link for reference:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2012/06/06/windows-server-2012-which-version-of-the-smb-protocol-smb-1-0-smb-2-0-smb-2-1-or-smb-3-0-you-are-using-on-your-file-server.aspx